# Tailwind theme customisation gridTemplateColumns not working

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to customise grid-template-columns but it is not working. I am adding gridTemplateColumns in the extend in tailwind.config file like it says in the docs but it is not working. Can someone help?

tailwind.config

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xs':'250px',
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'md': '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      'lg': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }
    },
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        'gridCol': 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr))',

      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

code

```
<div className='grid grid-rows-2 gridCol gap-y-6'>
            <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
            <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
            <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
            <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
            <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
            <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your classes you need to write `grid-col-gridCol` instead of just `gridCol`. So this should be your HTML:

```
<div className='grid grid-rows-2 grid-col-gridCol gap-y-6'>
        <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
        <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
        <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
        <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
        <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
        <WeatherHighlightCards title='Sun'/>
</div>
```